# JAVA new file or directory creation returns false

Tags: java, file

I tried to create a new file from `java.io.File` but it's method, `createNewFile()`, returns false (as well as `setWritable(true)` and `mkdirs()`).

Is it a permission problem? How can I change this behavior?

Extra Info:

- `File.exists()` returns true.
- `createNewFile()` doesn't throw any exceptions.
- The user I am running from has permission to create files in the directory but `canWrite()` returns false.
- Also, I'm using Eclipse if that changes anything.

Comment: According to the Java SE 7 documentation, the method only returns false if the file already exists. An ioexception is thrown otherwise.

Comment: Return of false would not be a permission issue. It would through an exception.

Comment: Consider using `Files.createFile` added in Java 7 if you want to get more feedback about problems which you may faced. Also read http://java7fs.wikia.com/wiki/Why_File_sucks

Comment: @PEMapModder, How can the file already exist if I `createNewFile()` has no argument?

Comment: @Pshemo Thanks for the editing and guidance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Javadoc it says that a new file will be created only if the file doesn't exist already.
Since File.exists() return true it means that the file exists and createNewFile will always return false until the file is deleted.
[java.io.File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html)
*Atomically creates a new, empty file named by this abstract pathname if and only if a file with this name does not yet exist.*

In general if you have permissions issue in software the recommended way to tackle it would be:

1. Test from a shell if the file can be created. If not fix the permissions.
2. Check if the java executable is running with your own permissions (maybe it has the SUID flag?).
3. Check if there are JAVA security policies that deny you access to the file system.